# Postgresql: Sort Results based on maximum number of matches in table columns

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

**EDITED BASED ON COMMENTS**

I have 2 tables **posts** and **categories**. The structure and sample data are as follows:

```
POSTS
ID    NAME                  DESCRIPTION              CATEGORY_ID
--  -----------------   -------------------          -----------
1   For Song Lovers     A post all about music            8
2   For Music Lovers    About passion of music            8
3   I love songs        Listing favourite songs           8
4   Rock Music          ImagineDragon                     6
5   Retro Music         Old choice musical themes         7

CATEGORIES
ID    NAME
--  -----------------
6   Artists
7   Entertainment
8   Music
```

I would like to sort records in such a way that:

1. Posts with matched **keyword** in name, description and category name appears first, followed by
2. Posts with matched **keyword** in name, description followed by
3. Posts with matched **keyword** in name followed by
4. Posts with matched **keyword** in description followed by
5. Posts with matched **keyword** in category

The resultant output I would like to have is (if **keyword=music**):

```
OUTPUT
---------
Post ID#2
Post ID#5
Post ID#4
Post ID#1
Post ID#3
```

I've been able to write 5 queries and combine it to have unique records. But that is not the optimised solution. Here's what I tried:

```
(
SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" INNER JOIN "categories" ON "categories"."id" = "posts"."category_id" WHERE posts.name iLIKE ('%music%') AND posts.description iLIKE ('%music%') AND categories.name iLIKE ('%music%')
+
SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE posts.name iLIKE ('%music%') AND posts.description iLIKE ('%music%')
+
SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts"  WHERE posts.name iLIKE ('%music%')
+
SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts"  WHERE posts.description iLIKE ('%music%')
+
SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" INNER JOIN "categories" ON "categories"."id" = "posts"."category_id" WHERE categories.name iLIKE ('%music%')
).uniq
```

I even tried to write a single query but that is not returning me the desired result (with obvious reason that I am not using GROUP OR COUNT)

```
SELECT posts.* FROM posts INNER JOIN categories ON categories.id = posts.category_id
WHERE (
  (posts.name iLIKE ('%music%') AND posts.description iLIKE ('%music%') AND categories.name iLIKE ('%music%'))
  OR (posts.name iLIKE ('%music%') AND posts.description iLIKE ('%music%'))
  OR (posts.name iLIKE ('%music%'))
  OR (posts.description iLIKE ('%music%'))
  OR (categories.name iLIKE ('%music%')))
```

Please suggest how can I achieve the same with above SQL.

Environment Details:

**Database**: PostgreSQL

**Version**: postgres (PostgreSQL) 9.4.5

Comment: I don't know Postgresql, but perhaps you can define name and description columns etc to have a case insensitive collation?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know PostgreSQL supports booleans, so this should match your description, sort by seperate columns:

```
SELECT posts.* FROM posts INNER JOIN categories ON categories.id = posts.category_id
WHERE  -- can be simplified to 
      LOWER(posts.name)        iLIKE ('%music%')
   OR LOWER(posts.description) iLIKE ('%music%')
   OR LOWER(categories.name)   iLIKE ('%music%')
ORDER BY -- FALSE probably sorts lower than TRUE, thus DESC
  LOWER(posts.name)        iLIKE ('%music%') DESC, posts.name,
  LOWER(posts.description) iLIKE ('%music%') DESC, posts.description
  LOWER(categories.name)   iLIKE ('%music%') DESC, categories.name
```

Another remark: `iLike` is case insensitive, why do you apply `LOWER` then? This should return the same result:

```
SELECT posts.* FROM posts INNER JOIN categories ON categories.id = posts.category_id
WHERE  -- can be simplified to 
      posts.name        iLIKE ('%music%')
   OR posts.description iLIKE ('%music%')
   OR categories.name   iLIKE ('%music%')
ORDER BY -- FALSE probably sorts lower than TRUE, thus DESC
   posts.name        iLIKE ('%music%') DESC, posts.name,
   posts.description iLIKE ('%music%') DESC, posts.description
   categories.name   iLIKE ('%music%') DESC, categories.name
```

And now combine this with @JuanCarlosOropeza's answer :-)

Comment: I dont think you need combine with mine. I check and you are right you can sort for boolean result, and false go first. And `.. DESC, posts.name,` make your order better than mine.

Comment: But you should probably consider [**text search**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/textsearch.html) those iLike probably **can't** use any index and can be a bottle neck if db growth to big.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza: I stil like your ORDER better, it's simplified. In PostgreSQL NULLs are considered higher than any value and if you want to sort `DESC` you might add `NULLS LAST`.

Answer (score 2):

```
 ORDER BY 
       CASE WHEN LOWER(posts.name) iLIKE ('%music%') THEN posts.name END,
       CASE WHEN LOWER(posts.description) iLIKE ('%music%') THEN posts.description END,
       CASE WHEN LOWER(categories.name) iLIKE ('%music%') THEN categories.name END,
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @juan-carlos-oropeza and @dnoeth for your responses. Based on your suggestions and snippet, I have come up with below and able to solve this

```
ORDER BY
  CASE WHEN posts.name iLIKE ('%music%') AND posts.description iLIKE ('%music%') AND categories.name iLIKE ('%music%') THEN 0 END,
  CASE WHEN posts.name iLIKE ('%music%') AND posts.description iLIKE ('%music%') THEN 1 END,
  CASE WHEN posts.name iLIKE ('%music%') THEN 2 END,
  CASE WHEN posts.description iLIKE ('%music%') THEN 3 END,
  CASE WHEN categories.name iLIKE ('%music%') THEN 4 END
```